# old-school screen blitting with c++?

Tags: c++, windows, screen

if I wanted to do some awesome old-school screen-blitting like the olden-day viruses that crawled around your screen, how could I pull that off in C++?
Any tips or clues appreciated.
Thanks

Btw, the OS is Windows

edit:
the shear number of down-votes to this question (-3 atm) can only mean that people don't understand my intentions. I'm neither wanting to do anything malicious nor pointless. What would you do if I asked how to interact with the sound chip on a Commodore 64? There are hundreds of people who do it every day, not because it's practical, but because it's fun.

Comment: if this 'charlie gordon' did anything related, I can't find it through all the political and storybook garbage on google under that name :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be to use layered windows.  not entirely trivial, but you can create a layered window and then supply your own content updates for that window using alpha blending so you could have objects transparently appear on top of your screen that way.  you might also be able to directly draw to the screen device context, but it would probably get cleared next update so I'm thinking a layered window would be the best way to do it and give the impression of what you're talking about.

Comment: sounds interesting. Would it be able to overlay all windows or just a parent? perhaps a link would help if you have one

Comment: Wow, great material! wouldn't work on 98 but that's not much of a sacrifice these days.

Comment: yay! I have dozens of little animated sprites invading my desktop :D